# Batch script to delete files in folder that does not contain certain word

Tags: batch-file, scripting, textedit

I am new to **batch scripting** . I need to delete all files in a folder that **DOES NOT** contains some word in the file

found this code

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd C:\Users\admin\Desktop\bat
findstr /ip /c:"importantWord" *.txt > results.txt
popd
endlocal
```

So how i can WHITE list this files, and delete all other?
Or i think there is easy way with just check if **!contains** and delete
but i don`t know how?

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly, this problem could be solved in a very simple way combining these `findstr` switches: /V that show results when the search string is *not* found, and /M that show just *the name* of the files; that is:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd C:\Users\admin\Desktop\bat
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /ipvm /c:"importantWord" *.txt') do del "%%a"
```

Unfortunately, the combination of /V and /M switches don't properly work: the result of /V is based on *lines* (not *files*), so a modification in the method is needed:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd C:\Users\admin\Desktop\bat

rem Create an array with all files
for %%a in (*.txt) do set "file[%%a]=1"

rem Remove files to preserve from the array
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /ipm /c:"importantWord" *.txt') do set "file[%%a]="

rem Delete remaining files
for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('set file[') do del "%%a"
```

This method is efficient, particularly with big files, because `findstr` command report just the name of the files and stop searching after the first string match.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "pathToFolder=C:\FolderToEmpty"
SET "wordToSearch=ImportantWord"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir %pathToFolder% /b *.txt') DO (
    findstr /IP %wordToSearch% "%pathToFolder%\%%F">nul
    IF !ERRORLEVEL!==1 (
        DEL /Q "%pathToFolder%\%%F"
    )
)
```

You will have to set the proper path to the folder you want to delete the files from and to replace ImportantWord with the substring you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. Where shoud i specify *.txt files only?

Comment: Edited my answer for *.txt only.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "targetdir=C:\Users\admin\Desktop\bat"
pushd %targetdir%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do (
 findstr /i /p /v /c:"importantWord" "%%a" >nul
 if not errorlevel 1 echo del "%%a"
)
popd
endlocal
```

Not really sure what you want to do with `/p`files - files containing non-ansi characters appear to return errorlevel `1`for these. `if not errorlevel 1` will echo the files that do not contain the required string - remove the `echo` to actually delete the file(s)